# FetchPOV Timeout issue with Basilisk(Kusama)

Tags: validator, validation, validator-set

I am facing `fetchPOV` timeout issue with `basilisk chain` 100% of the time while `para-validating.`
I suspect that this could be a `geolocation issue(Singapore)` as many other `validators` in Singapore are facing this timeout issue as well.
I would like to know if there is any way I could resolve it.

Many thanks in advance!

[image]